# arrow functions: i can't access the object outside

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

how can I get access my "count" object inside the arrow function ??

```
const myCounter = {
    count: 0,
    increment: () => {
        this.count += 1   
        //i know that the arrow functions can't work with "this." ... so how we get access count ??
    },
    currentValue: () => {
        return this.count
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you can reference the object name instead of `this`: `myCounter` (but this is a bit odd to do, why not just use a full-fledged function?)

Comment: I've changed it to a regular function thnx

Answer (score 1):

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not have its own `this`, `arguments`, `super`, or `new.target`. These function expressions are best suited for non-method functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

So, if you need to use `this`, define the methods using the `function` keyword:

```
const myCounter = {
    count: 0,
    increment: function () {
        this.count += 1;
    },
    currentValue: function () {
        return this.count;
    }
}
```

Comment: so I can't use the arrow function in this case ?? ... I just want to learn

Comment: No, arrow functions do not well for methods in objects, because they don't have their own `this`. Check out the link in my answer, it explains everything in great detail. If something is unclear, ask and I'll do my best to answer.